# I need Checkbox and label on one row

Tags: silverstripe, userform

I am new in `silverstripe`. Made form with `silverstripe/userforms` module in CMS (3.3). I need Checkbox and label on one row. Now I have this:

[image]

Where I can edit these forms settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to style the form output with CSS:

```
form .field.optionset input {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
form .field.optionset ul label {
    padding-left: 24px;
}
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you,Thank you! You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Id use `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`

instead of

```
float: left;
clear: left;
```